# Regex to find number in front of a specific word in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to grab part of a string that contains a number and then a specific word after for example:

> 5,422 Comments, other text here and stuff

or

> 45 Comments stuff more, here

I have tried the code below but it does not get the number in front of the word, any ideas?

```
preg_match('/Comments\s*(\d+)/', $str, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: Your pattern matches numbers *after* `comments`...

Comment: ah ok, how would I match BEFORE Comments??

Answer (score 2):

This should work -

```
([\d,]+)[ ]+Comments
```

Demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/zQ7fO8)

Answer (score 1):

It will work with this regex:

```
(\d+)\s*Comments
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with following regex:

`[0-9]+\s*Comments`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No capture groups are required if you use a lookahead after matching the qualifying integers.  I've improved the validation on the numeric expression to dignify/allow the potential thousands placeholders.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WC5Lv))

```
$strings = [
    '5,422 Comments, other text here and stuff',
    '2 Comments, not great!',
    '4/4/2009 21 Comments',
    'This one is a whopper: 1,234,567,890 Comments'
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    echo preg_match('~\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?= Comments)~', $string, $m) ? $m[0] : 'no match';
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
5,422
2
21
1,234,567,890
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not just `explode` it ?

```
$str='5,422 Comments';
echo array_shift(explode(' ',$str)); //"prints" 5,422
```

Comment: My string is part of a longer string for example: "5,422 Comments with some other text here and 43 here"

Comment: The code will still grab you `5,422` from your string `5,422 Comments with some other text here and 43 here` . The [**Demo**](https://eval.in/116283)